# java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method minus() on null object - Jenkins

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

Hi I am trying to run python app inside ec2 instance using jenkins pipelines. I am usign `publish over ssh` plugin to run the command inside ec2 instance but having an error. I am posting the code with error image in the question. Any help would be appreciated

```
pipeline {
  agent any
    
  tools {nodejs "node"}
    
  stages {
        
    stage('Git') {
      steps {
        git 'https://github.com/***/Jenkins-NodeJs'
      }
    }
     
    stage('Build') {
      steps {
        sh 'pwd'
        sh 'npm install'
        sh 'npm install express'
      }
    }      
     stage('Deployment') {
        steps {
            script {
                sshPublisher(publishers: [
                    sshPublisherDesc(
                        configName: "${env.ec2-user}",
                        transfers: [
                            sshTransfer(
                                sourceFiles: "/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Nodejs-pipelines/app.js",
                                execCommand: "cd nodejs, cp -f app.js "
                            )
                        ],
                        usePromotionTimestamp: false,
                        useWorkspaceInPromotion: false,
                        verbose: false
                    )]
                )
            }
        }
    }       
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: this looks suspect: `${env.ec2-user}`.. could you try a diffferent name for variable such as `${env.user}`

Comment: i have created a user that can ssh into the user and set its name to `ec2-user` so I was using this to refer to that user

Comment: if the config name is "ec2-user" then just use that value directly without the ${} as this is trying to resolve a variable, .e.g. : `configName: "ec2-user"`

Comment: How can I access app.js, like I am cloning the git repo but what command would I give in `exec command` to copy app.js inside ec2 instance?

Comment: not sure, i'd create a different question for that one